# Windows search: how to find all files with specified extension and wildcard (like *.csv, *.log, etc)

Tags: windows, search, windows-7, wildcard

Using the search input box in File Explorer, how do I find a filename with a specific extension?

**Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example**

I'd like to recursively find all comma-separated files in a folder, typically with a `.csv` extension. For what reason I cannot fathom, all of the following attempts fail to provide this result; they give me a massive list of stuff that I don't need:

```
*.csv
.csv
name: *.csv
name:=*.csv
```

I would expect at least one of these to simply print all files with a `.csv` extension in a sortable list.

This is one of those maddening things that **should** be simple, but for some reason, is not. I will resist the urge to use profanity, and pine for the search from UNIX, Linux, Windows XP, etc.. which actually make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I just use "csv" and make sure "All subfolders" is selected
[image]

Comment: This searches inside the files and returns a bunch of junk. I should specify Windows 7 maybe.

Comment: Then in "Advanced options" drop down make sure "File Contents" is not checked

Answer (score 0):

[Windows Desktop Search: Advanced Query Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/lwef/-search-2x-wds-aqsreference):

`ext:.csv`

[Windows 7: Advanced tips for searching in Windows](http://web.archive.org/web/20160303025751/http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/advanced-tips-for-searching-in-windows):

`System.FileName:~>".csv"`

Not sure if there is a trick to stop it searching compressed containers or force it to search the entire disk instead of just the index.

Windows Search can never be trusted to find all files, use [Everything](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_(software)), [Agent Ransack](https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/) or similar [3rd-party tools](https://web.archive.org/web/20190524145917/https://www.lifewire.com/11-free-file-search-tools-1356644) if you really are serious about file searching.